# Table inside table with different styles?

Tags: css, html-table

How to make two different styles for two tables table cells that one cells of them is inside another table?

I have two css styles:

```
table.style1 { /* any styles */}
table.style1 td { /* any styles */}
```

and

```
table.style2 { /* any styles */}
table.style2 td { /* any styles */ }
```

In code i have somting like this:

```
<table class="style1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table class="style2">
            <tr><td>bla bla<td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

and the results is - all of `<td>` table cells in second table (with style2) are with style1... !

How to make two different css stile, when I have table inside table?

Comment: check [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working as you'd hope.  Perhaps create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code. I am sure it works fine.

```
table.style1 { /* any styles */}

table.style1 td { /* any styles */}
```

and

```
table.style1 table.style2 { /* any styles */}

table.style1 table.style2 td { /* any styles */}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to select the different table cells http://jsfiddle.net/HR8Bg/2/

```
.style1 td {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

.style1 td td {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can follow below code

For Table 1

> table .style1 { /* any styles */}
>
> table .style1 td { /* any styles */}

For Table 2

> table .style1 .style2 { /* any styles */}
>
> table .style1 .style2 td { /* any styles */}

Comment: table name is .style1 you can's use space between table and .style1 in css. this selects the .style1 element in table.

Comment: We can use with spaces also it will work. It will select table then style1 class and style2 class. We are using it in our appliction